# constraints reverting back to original position when width is increased

Tags: slider, constraints, var, nslayoutconstraint

the slider changes the position of the object to its original position. You can see whites goin on the gif below. I just want when the user changes the size for the object to stay in its original position and not revert back to its original. I guess this is all being affected by var backCon.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var backBox = UIButton()
    
    
    var slider = UISlider()
    
    var panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
    var backCon = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    
    var widthConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint?
    
    var tim = 50.0
    var slidermultiplier: CGFloat = 0.6
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [backBox,slider].forEach{
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor(
                red: .random(in: 0.0...1),
                green: .random(in: 0.9...1),
                blue: .random(in: 0.7...1),
                alpha: 1
            )
            
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            slider.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            slider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.1),
            slider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 1),
            
        ])
        
        widthConstraints = backBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: slidermultiplier)
        
        backCon = [
            backBox.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            
            backBox.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: CGFloat(tim)),
            backBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.5),
            widthConstraints!,
            
        ]
        
        panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.draggedView(_:)))
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(backCon)
        
        backBox.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(increase), for: .valueChanged)
        
        backBox.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        
    }
    
    @objc func increase() {
        
        slidermultiplier = CGFloat(slider.value)
        widthConstraints?.isActive = false
        widthConstraints = backBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: slidermultiplier)
        widthConstraints?.isActive = true
    }
    
    @objc func draggedView(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        backBox.center = CGPoint(x: backBox.center.x + translation.x , y: backBox.center.y + translation.y)
        
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        
    }
    
    @objc func sliderr() {
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(backCon)
        
        backCon = [
            
            backBox.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            
            backBox.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: CGFloat(-tim)),
            backBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.3),
            widthConstraints!,
        ]
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(backCon)
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will almost always run into problems when using auto-layout constraints, and then explicitly setting frame values (include `.center`).

So, like you did with the Width constraint, you'll want to create constraints for Leading and CenterY so you can update those instead of setting `.center =`:

```
@objc func draggedView(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    
    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
    
    // update backBox Leading and CenterY constraints
    backBoxLeading.constant += translation.x
    backBoxCenterY.constant += translation.y
    
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
    
}
```

Here's a complete implementation (modification of your code). The `//` comments should make things pretty clear:

```
class SamViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var backBox = UIButton()
    
    var slider = UISlider()
    
    var panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

    // constraint we will modify when slider is changed
    var backBoxWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!

    // constraints we will modify when backBox is dragged
    var backBoxCenterY: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var backBoxLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    var tim = 50.0
    var slidermultiplier: CGFloat = 0.6
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [backBox,slider].forEach{
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor(
                red: .random(in: 0.0...1),
                green: .random(in: 0.9...1),
                blue: .random(in: 0.7...1),
                alpha: 1
            )
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            slider.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            slider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.1),
            slider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 1),
            
        ])

        // backBox Width constraint
        backBoxWidth = backBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: slidermultiplier)
        
        // backBox CenterY constraint
        backBoxCenterY = backBox.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        
        // backBox Leading constraint
        backBoxLeading = backBox.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: CGFloat(tim))
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // backBox Height is constant
            backBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.5),
            
            backBoxWidth,
            backBoxLeading,
            backBoxCenterY,
            
        ])
        
        panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(draggedView(_:)))
        
        backBox.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(increase), for: .valueChanged)
        
        backBox.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        
        // we start the backBox Width at "slidermultiplier" of view, so
        //  start the slider at "slidermultiplier"
        slider.setValue(Float(slidermultiplier), animated: false)
        
    }
    
    @objc func increase() {
        
        slidermultiplier = CGFloat(slider.value)

        // update backBox Width constraint
        backBoxWidth.isActive = false
        backBoxWidth = backBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: slidermultiplier)
        backBoxWidth.isActive = true
        
    }
    
    @objc func draggedView(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        
        // update backBox Leading and CenterY constraints
        backBoxLeading.constant += translation.x
        backBoxCenterY.constant += translation.y
        
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        
    }

}
```